# Changing text inside of an html <em> tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I only want to change the exact word that matches inside of an  tag, not all  tags. Is onload the best way to do this? I tried using str_repace in php but for some reason it worked on one page but not on the page i need it to work on.

```
<?php 
     $var = "<em>Bicycle</em>";
     echo str_replace($var, "Bicycle", "(something different)");
    ?>
```

Right now I've tried a few different html dom methods and some javascript too.

```
  <em>Bicycle</em>

<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("em").innerHTML = "(something different)";
</script>
```

---

```
<?php foreach ($this->components as $id => $comp): ?>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/' . $comp->img_src) ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->translate(sprintf($comp->translation_key, 'name')) ?>">
            </td>
            <td class="col2">
                <?php echo $this->translate(sprintf($comp->translation_key, 'name')) ?>
                <em><?php echo $this->translate(sprintf($comp->translation_key, 'description')) ?></em>
            </td>
            <td class="col3">
                <?php echo $this->formCheckbox(
                    "insurance[$id]", '1', !empty($this->order['insurance'][$id]), array('class' => 'row-checkbox')
                ) ?>
                <label for="checkbox"><?php echo $this->translate(
                        'order_additional_insurance_checkbox_label'
                    ) ?></label>
            </td>
            <td class="col4"><?php echo $this->translate(sprintf($comp->translation_key, 'dimensions_metric')) ?>
                <em><?php echo $this->translate(sprintf($comp->translation_key, 'dimensions_customary')) ?></em>
            </td>
            <td class="col5">
                <span class="rent">$<?php echo $comp->price ?></span>
            </td>
            <td class="col6">
                <div class="field-holder counter-holder row-qty" data-max-val="99">
                    <?php echo $this->formText(
                        "components[{$id}][quantity]",
                        (int)$this->order['components'][$id]['quantity'],
                        array(
                            'class' => 'required-aggregate-quantity',
                            'id'    => "component_{$id}_quantity"
                        )
                    ) ?>
                    <a class="btn-top" href="#">top</a>
                    <a class="btn-bottom" href="#">bottom</a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="col7">
                <?php
                $rowCost = (int)$this->order['components'][$id]['quantity'] * $comp->price;
                ?>
                <span class="cost">$<?php echo number_format($rowCost, 2) ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Were focused on translation key 'name'.

Comment: if you do have jQuery loaded you can use, `$('em').html('something else');`

Answer (score 1):

Although you specified jQuery, you can do it with JavaScript, however you're using `getElementsByTagName` wrong.

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array, you have to specify which one in the array needs to be edited. The demo should give you sufficient information.

You are not specifying which one in the array needs to be changed (`document.getElementsByTagName("em").innerHTML`), hence nothing is changing.

```
<em>Hello</em>
<em>Hello</em>
<em>Hello</em>
<em>Hello</em>
<em>Hello</em>
<em>Hello</em>

document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].innerHTML = "GAH!";
```

Will return

```
GAH! Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0jqvn9v2/

Comment: I really like the idea of doing it this way, it's really simple and straight forward but the word "Bicycle" dynamically loads through a php foreach loop.

Comment: @thismethod then you'd use AJAX (GET) then in your success callback simply `document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].innerHTML = data`. Data being the data being passed back from the AJAX.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure i know how to do that.

Comment: @thismethod do you know how to do the ajax part? If so I can make a simple example (you'd have to edit a little bit) for the PHP part.

Comment: I would have to say i'm a bit better with the php part.

Comment: @thismethod add your PHP code to your OP and I'll see what i can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86745/discussion-between-thismethod-and-script47).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)** with callback function to iterate over them. For replacing text use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

```js
$('em').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace("Bicycle", "(something different)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em>Bicycle</em>
```

If content is specific then,

```js
$('em').html(function(i, v) {
  return v === "Bicycle" ? "(something different)": v;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em>Bicycle</em>
```

Comment: Will this work even if the word "bicycle" dynamically loads as it iterates through a php foreach loop?

Comment: it's not statically on the page.